# How do I stop a mother from breastfeeding?

Tags: rimworld, rimworld-biotech

My colony recently welcomed a dirtmole hybrid into its community. The lil' tyke has -4 metabolism, which means a x200% food requirement, and had not reached one quadrum in age before coming down with "gut worms", which adds +100% food requirement until recovery (for a combined **400%**(!) normal food requirement).

Combined with the fact that babies have smaller stomachs than fully-grown pawns (and can thus, go less time between meals before becoming "hungry"), this means the newborn is constantly summoning its hardworking mother to keep it fed; which she struggles to do (since the baby consumes breastmilk faster than she can produce it).

To save time, I had my colonists create jars of baby food, but the mother doesn't seem to acknowledge it exists -- whenever the infant hungers, she immediately drops everything to rush halfway across the map to breastfeed.

Is there anything I can do to force the pawns to use the baby food to rescue poor Mom from the feedback loop of eternal, gut worms-induced, nursing?

Comment: If you have the cryptosleep technology thing, you could probably freeze 'em down until the gutworms pass. Or the similar bioregeneration thing that can remove all injuries and scars etc. But these are late game technologies so maybe not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, gutworms do not pass on their own -- they require 300% medical tend, which means they are permanent without effective treatment.

Comment: I think you can drag someone out of cryptosleep, tend to them, then show 'em back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, infants have a special **Feeding** tab that's dedicated to setting this, specifically. While I couldn't find a way to mandate regular feeding instead of breastfeeding, preventing the mother from handling the task entirely ensures she won't be held captive by her voracious spawn.

[image]